# Select 'this' object of clicked element only (not the other elements within the same class)

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to change buttons text on click (using Bootstrap 4). I have a problem with using the correct syntax.

My html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton2">
  Option 1                  
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton2">
  Type 1                  
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton3">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Type 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Type 3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function () {

  $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text());

});
```

To rephrase - when I click on one button and change its value, the other one changes too...

So I would like to change this value of the only clicked.

Comment: You have used `id="dropdownMenuButton2"` more than once. Each `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `html` of the `.btn` relative to your link.

You can do that by selecting the closest `.btn-group` to your link, then searching for `.btn` inside it :

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.btn').html($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.btn').html($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton2">
  Option 1                  
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton2">
  Type 1                  
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton3">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Type 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Type 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `$(this).closest('.btn').html($(this).text());` would not work? It looks for the closest btn from link?

Comment: @lovemyjob because `.btn` is not a parent of your link. It's the sibling of the parent of the link.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.btn').html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton2">
  Option 1                  
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton2">
  Type 1                  
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton3">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Type 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Type 3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function () {

$(this).parent().find(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: I did, But pressed ctrl + z instead of ctrl + c